# C program to reverse a string, I get write access violation

Tags: c, string

```
#include <Stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reversestr(char* str);
void main()
{
    char* str = { "I love Job" };
    printf("%s\n", str);
    reversestr(str);
    printf("\nAfter:%s\n", str);
}
void reversestr(char* str)
{
    int length,i;
    char* a, * b,temp;
    length = strlen(str) - 1;
    a = str;
    b = str;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        b++;
    for (i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
        a++;
        b--;
    }
}
```

I get error in *a=*b.
The error:
[image: Error]

I did it with explanation from google its very similar to solutions I found but it doesn't work for me even that I copied their solution either.

Comment: Writing to a string literal is undefined behavior, which often manifests as an access violation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to a string literal (writing to a string literal is undefined behavior). Replace:

```
char* str = { "I love Job" };
```

with

```
char str[] = "I love Job";
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above try to change:

```
char * str = ...
```

To:

```
char str[] = ...
```

When you save text in previous way, there is much chance that your string will get to .rodata section ( read only data ) so you receive an access violation error when you try to modify data in .rodata..